# Drupal 8 version of CiviVRM Membership Roles Sync?

Tags: drupal-8, roles, sync

Is there a Drupal 8 version of the CiviCRM Membership Roles Sync module, or is one planned?  I can't see it, or any opportunity to configure an equivalent facility.

Answer (score 1):

There is a alpha version for d8(https://www.drupal.org/project/civicrm_member_roles) which seems to be working for me.

Comment: we have been using it for both D8 and D9 sites - maybe we should try and help get it off alpha?

Comment: Yes, I did see that one, but was put off by the security status and the apparent lack of any active development effort.